# exclude regular expression

Tags: regex, apache, httponly, mod-headers

I have a regular expression for the HttpOnly configuration :

`Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure`

For Appdynamics EUM, i want to exclude from this regular expression everything that begin with "ADRUM" (without quotes).

How can i proceed ?

Thanks a lot for your help

Best regards !
Ludo

Comment: I added tags for `apache` and `mod-headers`, because this isn't really a question about regex, or a question about httponly, but a question about how to configure apache to do a certain thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do what you want. I'm afraid it's not tested, but the principle is this:

1) if the Set-Cookie header starts with ADRUM, then set the env variable ADRUM_cookie.

2) if the ADRUM_cookie env variable is /not/ set, edit the Set-Cookie header.

```
SetEnvIf Set-Cookie ^ADRUM ADRUM_cookie
Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure env=!ADRUM_cookie
```